# If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are NOT both continuous at some point $c$, does this imply that $f(x) + g(x)$ is also not continuous at point $c$?

Tags: limits, continuity

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are NOT both continuous at some point $c$, does this imply that $f(x) + g(x)$ is also not continuous at point $c$?

I know that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous then we know for sure $f(x) + g(x)$ is continuous, but I don't know if it is required for both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be continuous at $c$ for $f(x) + g(x)$ to be continuous at $c$.

Comment: Take any awful function $f$, then consider $g=-f$.

Comment: Of course not.  Let h be  perfectly nice "very" continuous function.  Let f be a "nasty" very discontinuous function, then g=h-f will be dicintinuous while f +g=h.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $f(x) = \operatorname{sgn(x)}, g(x) = -\operatorname{sgn(x)}$. Then $f + g = 0$ is continuous.

In general, you can let $g = -f + \phi$, where $\phi$ is any continuous function.

Comment: Not nesc. relevent but what is sgn (x)?  Is it sgn (x) = 1 in X is pos, -1 if x is negative and 0 if 0 or something like that?

Comment: @fleablood https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Answer (score 0):

If f+g = h, then it follows, g=h-f.  h can be as continuous as you like.  If f is "unruly" and discontinuous at c, so can g=h-f while f+g =h.

Simplest example.  f(x)= 0 if x $\ne $ 1 while f (1)=1.  Let g(x)=1 if x $\ne $ 1 while g (1)=0.  Then f+g (x)=1 for all x.

More fun is f(x)=x if x is rational but 0 otherwise while g (x)=x if x is irrational but 0 otherwise.